# Accessing APP_USER inside Javscript - set field value

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a button that will process the selected rows in an Interactive Grid. It works fine. I want to add in an audit value to populate a column when this function is used. Where the LOCKED column is set to 1 I want the LOCKED_BY column to be set to :APP_USER.

How do I access the value from within the piece of Javascript? :APP_USER doesn't work nor does the $v() method as far as I can see.

Where am I going wrong?

```
var r = g.getSelectedRecords();
var v 

for(i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
    v = g.model.getValue(r[i], 'WARN');
    if (v == '1') {
        g.model.setValue(r[i], 'LOCKED', '0');
    }
    else {
        g.model.setValue(r[i], 'LOCKED', '1');
        g.model.setValue(r[i], 'LOCKED_BY', $v('APP_USER')); //WANT TO SET THIS VALUE HERE
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I never do it but I would try to use :APP_USER  as default value for an hidden item and then access the item as DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs in the browser and so can only see items that are actually rendered on the page (i.e. page items, not application items).  You could create a hidden page item (perhaps on page 0 if needed on all pages) for this purpose.  However, if your Javascript is defined within APEX (not in a separate .js file) then you should be able to do this:

```
g.model.setValue(r[i], 'LOCKED_BY', '&APP_USER.');
```

`&APP_USER.` will be substituted with the value of APP_USER when the page is rendered.